# e_validation_failure: validation exception adonisjs

Tags: node.js, validation, amazon-ec2, adonis.js

I am facing this error "e_validation_failure: validation exception" only on prod enviroment... I am using Adonis 5, in my local everything runs correctly, in stage as well.

my controller looks like this:

```
public async store({ request, response }: HttpContextContract) {
    response.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
    try {
      const payload = await request.validate(SignupUserValidator); 
      await UserService.store(payload);

      return responseWithSuccess(response);
    } catch (error) {
      return responseWithError(response, error.message);
    }
  }
```

my validator looks like this:

```
import { schema, rules } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator';
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext';
import { UserRoleEnum } from 'Contracts/enums';

export default class SignupUserValidator {
  constructor(protected ctx: HttpContextContract) {}

  public schema = schema.create({
    first_name: schema.string({ trim: true }, [rules.minLength(2)]),
    last_name: schema.string({ trim: true }, [rules.minLength(2)]),
    password: schema.string({}, [rules.minLength(8), rules.confirmed()]),
    email: schema.string({}, [
      rules.email(),
      rules.unique({ table: 'users', column: 'email' }),
    ]),
    role: schema.enum([UserRoleEnum.CLIENT, UserRoleEnum.COWORKING] as const),
    photo_id: schema.number.optional([rules.exists({ table: 'photos', column: 'id' })]),
    personal_address: schema.object.optional().members({
      fulltext: schema.string.optional({ trim: true }),
      latitude: schema.number.optional(),
      longitude: schema.number.optional(),
      city: schema.string.optional(),
      state: schema.string.optional(),
      country: schema.string.optional({ trim: true }),
    }),
    personal_phone: schema.string({}, [rules.maxLength(14), rules.minLength(10)]),
    cowork: schema.object
      .optional([rules.requiredWhen('role', '=', UserRoleEnum.COWORKING)])
      .members({
        name: schema.string({ trim: true }),
        email: schema.string.optional({}, [
          rules.email(),
          rules.unique({ table: 'cowork_accounts', column: 'email' }),
        ]),
        phone: schema.string.optional({}, [rules.maxLength(14), rules.minLength(10)]),
        photo_id: schema.number.optional([
          rules.exists({ table: 'photos', column: 'id' }),
        ]),
      }),
    client: schema.object
      .optional([rules.requiredWhen('role', '=', UserRoleEnum.CLIENT)])
      .members({
        company_name: schema.string.optional({ trim: true }),
        company_email: schema.string.optional({}, [rules.email()]),
        company_phone: schema.string.optional({}, [
          rules.maxLength(14),
          rules.minLength(10),
        ]),
        company_address: schema.object.optional().members({
          fulltext: schema.string.optional({ trim: true }),
          latitude: schema.number.optional(),
          longitude: schema.number.optional(),
          country: schema.string.optional({ trim: true }),
        }),
        company_photo_id: schema.number.optional([
          rules.exists({ table: 'photos', column: 'id' }),
        ]),
      }),
  });

  public messages = {
    minLength: 'The {{ field }} must be at least {{ options.minLength }} characters',
    maxLength: 'The {{ field }} must have at most {{ options.maxLength }} characters',
    required: 'The {{ field }} is required',
    exists: 'The {{ field }} is invalid',
    number: 'The {{ field }} must be a number',
    string: 'The {{ string }} must be a string',

    'password_confirmation.confirmed': 'The passwords are different',
    'email.email': 'The email is not valid',
    'email.unique': 'User with email address already exists',
    'cowork.requiredWhen': 'The cowork object must be sent when the user is a coworking',
    'cowork.email.email': 'The email is not valid',
    'cowork.email.unique': 'Company with email address already exists',
    'client.requiredWhen': 'The client object must be sent when the user is a client',
  };
```

My request looks like this:

```
{
"first_name": "Dan",
"last_name": "Abreu",
"password": "secret1233",
"password_confirmation": "secret1233",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"role": "CLIENT",
"personal_phone": "1234567890",
"photo_id": null,
"personal_address": {
    "fulltext": "Rua do Lead",
    "city":"Gravatá",
    "state":"Pe",
    "country":"Brazil",
    "longitude": -10.00,
    "latitude": 1.00
},
"client": {
    "company_name": "my company",
    "company_email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "company_phone": "10800-0000",
    "company_photo_id": null,
    "company_address": {
        "fulltext": "Rua do labrador",
        "longitude": -10.00,
        "latitude": 1.00
    }
}
```

I am following the rules when creating the validator:

`node ace make:validator SignupUserValidator`

is anyone facing the same issue on aws ec2 enviroment?

I tried to validate the request with the validator I created and everything works fine on my local and stage env but on prod it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should not handle validation exception within the controller. This is what you are doing when you wrap the `request.validate` call in the umbrella `try...catch` block.

Removing the `request.validate` call from the `try...catch` block will solve this issue as Adonisjs is capable of handling and return the validation errors as response.

Technically, there is no issue with your code. However, you decided the trap all your errors within the `try...catch` block. When you do this, it is your responsibility to handle the errors.

Also note that it is recommended not to use an umbrella `try...catch` block within your controller code. Adonisjs is capable of controller error handling. You can customise the behaviour of the controller error handling in your global `Handler` file. See https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/exception-handling#handling-exceptions-globally